# Graphviz enforce ordering between nodes of different levels

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-layout

I have the following graph:

```
digraph {
  stylesheet = "..."
  subgraph cluster {
    b; c; g;
    {rank=same; b; g;}
  }
  a -> b;
  b -> c;
  c -> d;
  c -> e;
  f -> c;
  {rank=same; a; f;}
}
```

[image]

Is there any way to force/encourage the edge `f -> c` to pass between nodes `b` and `g`? I've tried a number of different strategies and graphviz refuses to both:

- keep `b` and `g` within the border, and
- allow `g` to appear of to the side and not interfere with the rest of the graph.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the **dot** algorithm does not want to route the *f->c* edge as you want.  However, the **neato** edge routing algorithm produces a closer result.  So we use **dot** to position the nodes and **neato -n** to route the edges.  Like so:

```
dot -Tdot myfile.gv >out.dot
neato -n -Tpng out.dot >myfile.png
```

Using this input:

```
 digraph {
  stylesheet = "https://g3doc.corp.google.com/frameworks/g3doc/includes/graphviz-style.css"
  nodesep=.5  // optional
  subgraph cluster {
    b 
    c; g 
    {rank=same; b; g;}
  }

  f -> g [style=invis]
  f:se -> c:nw [constraint=false]

  a -> b;
  b -> c;
  c -> d;
  c -> e;
}
```

Giving:
[image]

See https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords
And https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/

(Close enough?)

Comment: On the real graph (the one I provided here was a minimal example), it would be better if there was more space between `b` and `g` (there is a loooot of space on that line). I would also prefer not to modify the compilation process for ease of re-creation. Currently, my best idea is to remove `g` entirely and add it by hand post-generation.